# need help appending Javascript onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I'm trying to append javascript code when I click a button, but I think I messed up. If someone could help me with syntax. Maybe I'm doing it the wrong way; if someone has a better way to do it, it would be appreciated.

```
$("#btn_add").click(function(){   
 '<script>$(".selectcategory'+count+'").change(function() {var vv = ($(this).val());$( ".cat'+count+'" ).empty();$(".cat'+count+'").append("<input id="i_index" type="text" name="categorie[]" maxlength="255" style="width:80%" value="vv">");});</script>'
});
```

Comment: You don't have to use script tags. you can attach an event handler within another event handler

Comment: so many things wrong i dont even know where to start

Comment: @YuriyGalanter That way you bind an event handler many times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honostly there is a lot wrong in your code. I am learning Javascript myself at the moment, so maybe i won't provide the solution, but I am trying to help.

First of all, the script tag should be arround your code, not in it. Second use the single and double quotes correct. Last but not least, use some markup in your code. It's hard to see where the issue is.

```
<script>
$("#btn_add").click(function()
{   
    $(".selectcategory"+count).change(function()
    {
       var vv = ($(this).val());
       $(".cat"+count).empty();
       $(".cat"+count).append('<input id="i_index" type="text" name="categorie[]" maxlength="255" style="width:80%" value="vv">');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Greg, we were edditting the same thing, so I guess I am at least close ;)

Comment: ur right messing up with all those single quote and double quote now its working i forgot to put missing line on the code